# req.isAuthenticated() is returning false using NodeJS, Express and PassportJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

req.Authenticated always returning false, but the validation of entering wrong username and password showing perfectly.

this is passportjs authentication code

passport.js

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
        RegisterList.findById(id, function(err, user){
            console.log('deserializing user:', user);
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    /* Customer Login Config */
    passport.use('customer-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'username',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, username, password, done){
        process.nextTick(function(){
            RegisterList.findOne({'mobile_no' : username}, function(err, user){
                if(err)
                    return done(err);
                if(!user)
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No User Found'));
                if(user.password != password){
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Invalid password'));
                }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        });
    }));
```

this is my route code
routes

```
module.exports = function(router, passport){

    router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('customer-login', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true
    }));

    router.get('/home', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
        res.render('secured/customer-home', {user: req.user});
    });

};

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.session);
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

help me to sort out this problem...am stuck with this

Updated:

while using console.log(req.session)
am getting this
[image: Error Image]

Comment: Which failure route is the logic taking?  Also, i'm not liking the `!=` in your password failure logic.  You ought to be using the strict type version `!==`, or have another function call with a more robust check (ala the docs: http://passportjs.org/docs/username-password)

Comment: actually its not a problem...validation is working perfectly....

Comment: while logging in req.isAuthenticated() is returning false

Comment: What does logging `req.session` (in `isLoggedIn()`) show?

Comment: please see above i have update my error @robertklep

Comment: The empty `passport` in the session suggests that perhaps your `passport.deserializeUser()` is failing.

Comment: what i need to do now

Comment: Check if your client is sending the session cookies properly, and also make sure that `passport.deserializeUser()` is called (and working).

Comment: I found my solution, In my application i have two login separatly one for admin another one for client..both signup form is differrent..if i uncomment the admin passport.deserializeUser its working else not working, how can i do it for both User Collection and RegisterList Collection